# Perform function and then also perform whatever is passed as prop, ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a ripple effect from child button component but I also want to perform random functions with the button, but my ripple function stops the onClick props from reacting to whatever other function I pass it from the parent...

```
// jsx
return (
    <button
        className={button}
        onClick={(e) => {
            Ripple(e);
            props.onClick;
        }}>
        My Button
    </button>
);
```

This is my ripple function:

```
// styles
import './ripple.scss';

export default function Ripple(e) {
    const el = e.currentTarget;

    const circle = document.createElement('span');
    const diameter = Math.max(el.clientWidth, el.clientHeight);
    const radius = diameter / 2;

    circle.style.width = circle.style.height = `${diameter}px`;
    circle.style.left = `${e.clientX - el.offsetRight - radius}px`;
    circle.style.top = `${e.clientY - el.offsetTop - radius}px`;
    circle.classList.add('ripple');

    const ripple = el.getElementsByClassName('ripple')[0];

    if (ripple) {
        ripple.remove();
    }

    el.appendChild(circle);
}
```

Comment: Can you share what your ripple does?

Comment: @Domino987edited on main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call props.onClick, you are missing `()`:

```
return (
    <button
        className={button}
        onClick={(e) => {
            Ripple(e);
            props.onClick();
        }}>
        My Button
    </button>
);
```